# what does the '--project' means in webpack command line Interface?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I found **"lint": "tslint --project ."**  in someone's `package.json` file, but I don't get it --project means. And I didn't find any clue in webpack' doc.
**json'**

```
"script": {
"lint": "tslint --project ."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This flag is used to determine on which files linting process should be done

> -p, --project:
>
> ```
> The path or directory containing a tsconfig.json file that will be
> used to determine which files will be linted. This flag also enables
> rules that require the type checker.
> ```

[`tslint config`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/cli/)